# Can I develop software for Microsoft Surface on Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I want to develop a WinRT app for Surface.

There is one detail I cannot find anywhere. Will I be able to compile and run on the device using Windows 7 or I need to upgrade to Windows 8?

Comment: only if it's Surface x86. If it's surface RT, probably not, because that's an ARM platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't develop an RT "Modern" style app on Windows 7.  You'll need Windows 8 either installed as your main OS or hosted in a VM.

Comment: What do you mean by "modern". Did not know that there are several classes of surface apps.

Comment: "Modern" is a term used by some people to refer to "Windows Store apps."

Comment: Yep, Microsoft is calling it "modern" now for some reason.  It actually used to be called "Metro", which is still the more popular term.

Comment: Microsoft had to abondon Metro word due to trademark dispute. It is another story that they claim, ["It was never metro, it was always modern ui"](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/08/10/metro_is_modern_ui_now/), last year build sessions use "Metro style apps" words extensively.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to develop with virtual machine(Win8) in windows 7 unfortunately if you want to develop without virtual machine you have to upgrade it

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no. WinRT apps require windows 8 APIs, there is no support for building them on Windows 7. You can fake the environment out by setting up a virtual machine and developing on that.

Answer (score -1):

From Microsoft Surface SDK documentation:

"The Microsoft Surface 2.0 SDK provides the managed APIs and the tools you need to develop Surface applications. Applications that are built using the Surface SDK can run on devices made for Surface 2.0, and on Windows 7 computers..."

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815.aspx

Comment: That is the old Surface (now known as PixelSense). The OP is asking about the Windows 8 slate device.

Comment: That was the first link that was returned when I searched "Microsoft Surface Development Environment" on Google. Too bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: That's because there is no special SDK for the Surface tablet. You program the Surface tablet the same way you program any other Windows RT device.