# Is there any way to create a WinRT app using a Windows 7 development machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I develop software for Microsoft Surface on Windows 7 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257478/can-i-develop-software-for-microsoft-surface-on-windows-7-machine)

Is there any way to create a WinRT app using a Windows 7 development machine, or do I have to install the Windows 8 OS in order to develop for the WinRT platform?

Comment: The "duplicate" question asks whether Microsoft Surface apps can be developed on Windows 7. Technically that is the same question as this one, but that may not be obvious to people new to the subject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

WinRT is new platform available only in windows 8 (as of now). Because it is tightly built into kernel, it cannot be installed as separate package/installer on top of other operating system (like Win 7).

Win8 OS is mandatory to develop WinRT app.