# How can I develop a Windows RT app on Windows 7?

Tags: debugging, windows-7, windows-rt

I bought the Windows Surface RT because of the student discount. (just ~220€)
But the delivery was delay by about three weeks so I don't have it right now. Still I would like to start developing applications I can run on the windows Surface RT.

I can't find really much on google on how to develop apps for the RT.
But I did find a webpage that said C# would work.

I tried doing some research and I'm sure that I cannot use all libraries on the RT device.
So what LIBS can I use and how can I setup c# to be compiled for ARM. (and debug on my windows 7 pc)

Comment: Microsoft should have this information on their site. Google and Bing should also be able to locate it for you. StackOverflow should not be used as a replacement for some basic research on your part.

Comment: Well as said I already did that. But the microsoft site redirects me to the Visual Studio for windows 8.1. But as said in the OP I don't have windows 8.1 and own windows 7.

Comment: [Duplicate to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257478/can-i-develop-software-for-microsoft-surface-on-windows-7-machine)

Comment: bland This question is from 6 sep :/

Comment: @TimvanOsch You know, I did not even notice that! It was in the generic 'Top Questions' list for me though.